# How can I scrape a child span class using VBA?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I would like to use the below code to scrape the ranking position in one of amazon's sub categories (Candy & Chocolate Bars). Please see attached picture for the html code. Referring to "a-list-item" gives me a lot of results, however, the "#204" is not part of it. Thus, my question is two-fold: (i) is there a way to get all the items labeled "a-list-item" and (ii) is there a way that just gives me back the ranking position without pulling all other items. Option (ii) would be superior for my purposes.

Thanks for your time and efforts.

html code with target value

[image]

```
Public Sub social()
     
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   
    Dim WSactive As Worksheet
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    Set WBactive = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WSactive = WBactive.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    On Error Resume Next

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    With WSactive
        Dim results(0 To 4) ', counter As Long, i As Long
        With IE
            .Visible = False
            
                'If TBLurl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, w).Value <> "" Then
                    url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08X19ZCHS?ref=myi_title_dp"
                    .navigate url

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                    Dim aNodeList As Object, ele As Object, t As Date
                    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
                    t = Timer

                    Do
                        DoEvents
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Set ele = .document.querySelector(".rhpdm")
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
                    Loop While ele Is Nothing

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    
                    Set aNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll(".a-list-item")
                    Dim j As Long
                    For j = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
                       Debug.Print aNodeList.Item(j).innerText
                    Next j
                    Set aNodeList = Nothing: Set ele = Nothing
            .Quit 'close IE
        End With

    End With

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```

Comment: Use an open source library that is maintained by by a slew of developers instead of trying to roll your own one question at a time on StackOverflow: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only 1 Url shown and a css path to that node can be

```
Debug.Print .document.querySelector('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div #detailBullets_feature_div + ul .a-list-item .a-list-item').innerText
```

The + is an adjacent sibling combinator specifying ul that follows at same level an element with id detailBullets_feature_div. The spaces are descendant combinators, meaning elements on right are children  of elements on left of space. The . are class selectors for the class names of elements.

The html in your image appears to be slightly different from the provided url however. Your mileage with the above solution may vary. I have gone for positional matching on assumption other pages will have similar layout.

Even if you were doing a loop over different pages, pages as per the provided url would have only that one ranking to pick up (if as shown in your image).

---

You don't need the overhead of the browser. The following shows you how to get both rankings on the page (not just the one you showed) using xhr:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PrintRankings()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07YG6MTD3?ref=myi_title_dp&th=1", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

   Debug.Print html.querySelector("#detailBullets_feature_div + ul span > span").NextSibling.NodeValue
   Debug.Print html.querySelector("#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div #detailBullets_feature_div + ul .a-list-item .a-list-item").innerText
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for both the working code and the background information. much appreciated.

Comment: I am fascinated by this adjusted code: much leaner than mine.

two questions though:
(1) how do you know that "detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div" is the section where to start?
(2) is there a documentation I can read through all that?

Comment: I am using `Debug.Print html.querySelector("#productDetails_db_sections #productDetails_detailBullets_sections1 tr +tr +tr .td").innerText` to pull the ranking from the page below trying to replicate your code. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Here's the link:  [link](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B004FO4F4E/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?crid=21NT1JG9RQ01B&dchild=1&keywords=halloren+kugeln&qid=1614253511&sprefix=halloren%2Caps%2C216&sr=8-3-spons&psc=1&smid=A32LAVGANCQCM7&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzUTVDVkVSS1BIWlRGJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzQxODYzMjE2RExHOU85QzI5RCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNjQ4ODM1M1RPUTdUNkZJNTU5SyZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=)

Comment: (1) how do you know that "detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div" is the section where to start? Experience with css and html and a little exploration in the elements tab of browser (2) is there a documentation I can read through all that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors , https://flukeout.github.io/

Comment: _I am using Debug.Print html.querySelector("#productDetails_db_sections #productDetails_detailBullets_sections1 tr +tr +tr .td").innerText to pull the ranking from the page below trying to replicate your code. What am I doing wrong here?_   maybe html.querySelectorAll("#productDetails_db_sections tr + tr + tr span > span")  then take item(0) and item(1) of returned nodeList?

Comment: Thanks for sharing those links. The first one helped me to adjust my code using `~` (general sibling combinator). My code then looks as follows: `Debug.Print html.querySelector("#productDetails_db_sections tr + tr + tr span > span").innerText '>> gives back overall rank in grocery
   Debug.Print html.querySelector("#productDetails_db_sections tr + tr + tr span > span ~ span").innerText '>> gives back rank in candies`